# PHP zip class. Zip all directories in site root except one

Tags: php, class, function

I'm using this PHP class: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/9524.html

I use this code to make it work:

```
include('scripts/zip.php');

$directoryToZip = "./"; // This will zip all the file(s) in this present working directory 

$outputDir = 'backup/'; //Replace "/" with the name of the desired output directory. 
$zipName = 'backup_'.date('Y-m-d').'1.zip';

// If backup already exists, kill it
if(file_exists($outputDir.$zipName)){
    unlink($outputDir.$zipName);    
}

$createZipFile = new CreateZipFile; 

/* 
// Code to Zip a single file 
$createZipFile->addDirectory($outputDir); 
$fileContents=file_get_contents($fileToZip); 
$createZipFile->addFile($fileContents, $outputDir.$fileToZip); 
*/ 

//Code toZip a directory and all its files/subdirectories 
$createZipFile->zipDirectory($directoryToZip,$outputDir); 
$fd = fopen($outputDir.$zipName, "wb");
fwrite($fd,$createZipFile->getZippedfile()); 
fclose($fd);
```

Now as you see I tell it to .zip all directories and files using this variable:

```
$directoryToZip = "./";
```

I need to make one exception:
I don't want the script to .zip the backup directory.

How do I add an exception?

Comment: Can't access the code, could you post it on pastebin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the "parseDirectory" method, as show below:

```
<?php

include('zip.php');  

class myCreateZipFile extends CreateZipFile {
  protected function parseDirectory($rootPath, $separator="/"){ 
    global $directoryToZip, $outputDir;

    $fileArray1 = parent::parseDirectory($rootPath, $separator);
    $prefix = $directoryToZip.$separator.$outputDir;
    $fileArray2 = array();
    foreach ($fileArray1 as $file) {
      if (strncmp($file, $prefix, strlen($prefix)) != 0) {
        $fileArray2[] = $file;
      }
    }
    return($fileArray2);
  }
}

$directoryToZip = "./";   
$outputDir = 'backup/';
$zipName = 'backup_'.date('Y-m-d').'1.zip';
@unlink($outputDir.$zipName);     

$createZipFile = new myCreateZipFile;   
$createZipFile->zipDirectory($directoryToZip, $outputDir);  
if ($fd = fopen($outputDir.$zipName, "wb")) {
  fwrite($fd,$createZipFile->getZippedfile());  
  fclose($fd); 
}

?>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already solved this problem. But I'll accept your answer assuming it works :)